# Mocha and supertest: "For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves" error when using async await

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to test a route in my application, that deals with registering a new user. First, the test should remove all records from the collection(it's a test database), and then call the actual route. This is the code:

```
it('Test POST/register route', async () => {

        await User.deleteMany({})//Calling Mongoose method to first remove all records.

        await request(app)
            .post('/register')
            .send({ email: 'yoyo@gmail.com', password: 1234 })
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
                expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('error', null);                      
                const { id } = res.body.data;
                expect(typeof id).toBe('string');                   
            })        
 })
```

When i run this, i get an error:"For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

It works perfectly fine, once i remove the " await User.deleteMany({})" statement.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

Edit: the problem was jsut the actual time it took for the test to complete. once i use this.timeout(0) it passes.

Comment: Is it possible that the process simply is taking too long? Any `async` function will return a promise, and it will resolve provided no exception were thrown.

Comment: There's no problem with the code. Since the problem occurs at deleteMany, the conclusion is that it takes too much time to delete all records.

Comment: Yes, just before your comment, i edited my post. It was taking too long. Now the question is, why should such a test take more than 2 seconds? is it "normal"?